# MVC4: Windows Authentication on first Controller/Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication

I have set a global Authorize for this Windows-Integrated MVC4 web site:

```
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute());
    }
```

The default controller is a simple welcome page, and IE8 asks for the username password. The problem is that regardless of what username/password use to log in, it fails after 4 attempts with HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized.

Only if I make the first default controller set to [AllowAnonymous] does it let me in so that when I navigate to another action the prompted username/password it works.

It's like the web site has to "warm up?"

Question: How do I set the **default** controller/action to ask for **and accept** a username/ password?

[image]

Comment: I take it the `[AllowAnonymous]` solution doesn't work for you?

Comment: We don't want to allow in anyone to any page unless they are authenticated. Hyper secure site.

Comment: Then you need a security layer outside the website, since it's impossible to authenticate using ASP.NET MVC without allowing at least one controller method to work unauthenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `[Authorize]` as the attribute for the welcome page. That should not prompt for a username/password as long as the user has valid network credentials.